# How to set a fixed size for gtk grid

Tags: user-interface, julia, gtk

Currently I'm working on a non-resizable 576x512 `GtkWindow`,and I put a `GtkGrid` as its child. I want to divide the window into 9x8 areas, which means the size of each grid is 64x64.
I tried to set the `height-request` and `width-request` 64 for one of the grids, but only that grid had the right size. Then I made `row_homogeneous` and `height_homogeneous` true, but it still didn't show correctly.
So how can I let each grid 64x64?
(by the way all settings are default)

```
using Gtk
win=GtkWindow("Test",576,512;resizable=false,visible=true)
g=GtkGrid()
push!(win,g)
g[1,1]=GtkButton("A")
g[2,2]=GtkButton("B")
# what to do ?

showall(win)
```

---

the current main problem is the GtkWidget at (1,1) and (1,3) are neignbours instead of a space in between

Comment: Do keep in mind that there may be a couple pixels of padding around the grid and grid squares. It would help if you could [edit] your question to contain information like what widgets you're putting into the grid, screenshots of the window, and a [example]. It's hard to understand what you mean by "it doesn't show correctly" when we don't know what you're showing, or how you're showing it.

Comment: to test it, i just put GtkButton into the grid

Comment: Did you try setting sizes of the contained widgets instead?

Comment: yes i did but the result didn't change

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the key was to resize not the grid, but its children, to the needed size. I did nothing to the grid, but make sure every button contained in the grid was 64x64 and the layout scaled appropriately. Here is the code (in C++, I don't know Julia, sorry):

```cpp
#include <string>

#include <gtkmm.h>

constexpr int BTN_WIDTH = 64;
constexpr int WIN_WIDTH = 8 * 64;

constexpr int BTN_HEIGHT = 64;
constexpr int WIN_HEIGHT = 9 * 64;

class MainWindow : public Gtk::ApplicationWindow
{

public:

    MainWindow();

private:

    Gtk::Grid m_layout;

};

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    set_default_size(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT);
    set_resizable(false);

    // Add items to the grid:
    const int nbBtnsWide = WIN_WIDTH / BTN_WIDTH;
    const int nbBtnsTall = WIN_HEIGHT / BTN_HEIGHT;

    for(int row = 0; row < nbBtnsTall; ++row)
    {
        for(int column = 0; column < nbBtnsWide; ++column)
    {
        std::string btnText = "(" + std::to_string(row) + ", " + std::to_string(column) + ")";
            Gtk::Widget* button = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Button(btnText));

            // Here is the key : make each button 64 x 64. This will scale the grid appropriately.
        button->set_size_request(BTN_WIDTH, BTN_HEIGHT);

        m_layout.attach(*button, column, row, 1, 1);
    }
    }

    add(m_layout);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.examples.base");
  
    MainWindow window;
    window.show_all();
  
    return app->run(window);
}
```

Leaving me with this window:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but i don't need button in every grid, some places are empty so that i can't set the size like this

Comment: I don't think your use case will be working. You should put widgets in your grid as it is scaled appropriately from them. You could add empty labels, for example, to visually simulate no widgets.

Comment: well, it seems to meet the needs, but it just wastes too much resources. you know, i don't quite believe this is the only option